# Need to find which Microchip Company my dogs microchip came from

Tags: dogs

I purchased a puppy from a lady in my state who had him imported from Hungary.  He is microchipped but no one can tell which company it's from so we can get him in our name.  Previous owner did not do it either.  His paperwork is in Hungary and have tried to figure out who to reach out to.

Comment: Have vets tried to scan the chip? Depending on where in the world you live, there usually are only very few different chip types and vets or rescue organizations have scanners for the most common ones. If no-one around you is able to scan the chip, maybe consider implanting a new one. The original one might be damaged or not, but it's useless if no-one can scan it in case your dog gets lost.